# Восемь и осьминог

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Почему в некоторых однокоренных словах добавилось "в" перед "о", а в некоторых нет?Например "осьминог", но "восемь", "навострить уши", но "острый". Я знаю, что в древнеславянском языке число 8 писалось без начальной "в". В некоторых современных славянских языках такое написание существует и по сей день. Но с чем связано нерегулярное появление "в" перед "о" в русском языке?

Comment: Могу предложить почитать материал по [этой ссылке](https://studopedia.su/4_36077_lektsiya-.html). Более конкретно, ищите 5. "Синтагматические отношения", там, в частности, упоминается и "протеза" - так в лингвистике называют явление, о котором вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Но. Вопрос "почему" в лингвистике, как правило, не имеет ответа. В данном случае, кому-то когда-то захотелось добавлять "в" перед некоторыми словами на "о" (и "у"), и такое произношение прижилось. А в каких-то словах не прижилось.

Comment: Отмечаются довольно ранние примеры с гласной вставкой: осьмь выслала ГрБ № 724 (1166/1167); осьмь бьлъ 223 (1 четв. XIII). Образование формы осемь почти уравняло звуковой облик данного числительного с соседним счетным словом семь. Поэтому закрепление протезы, несомненно, поддерживалось отталкиванием от соседнего числительного, с которым наметилось «опасное», паронимическое сближение: семь ~ осемь. Кроме восточнославянского ареала, протетический согласный представлен на славянском западе — в кашубском, полабском и серболужицких языках. (Истор. грамматика ДРЯ. 2006)